# Proof of Cartan's theorem in Do Carmo's book

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

I would like to know why it is necessary to prove that $\widetilde{J}(l) = df_q(v) = df_q(J(l))$ to prove the Cartan's theorem below.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: There is a close link between the exponential map at a point $p \in M$ and the Jacobi fields along geodesics emanating from $M$. This link is given by the formula $\mathrm{d}\exp_p(v)w = J(1)$ where $J$ is the unique Jaobi field along $t \mapsto \exp_p(tv)$ with $J(0) = 0$ and $J'(0) = w$. Do Carmo is in fact implicitely refering to this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the equality in the post is necessary after observe that $J(l) = v$, $\widetilde{J}(l) = df_q(v)$ and $|\widetilde{J}(l)| = |J(l)|$, then $|df_q(v)| = |v|$.